# Web Subversion repository-browsing tool, with a twist

Tags: svn, browser, repository

I've seen a number of questions asking about a web SVN repository-browsing tool.  However, of the ones I've taken a look at, they either require a specific username/password to be configured, rely on default access to the repository being available, or require a separate user database outside Subversion.

In a corporate setting, SVN repository admins may lock down the repository so that there isn't a "guest" or "anonymous" account that has access.  And if they're using the domain username/password for access to these, it's not really a great idea to embed a real user's authentication details into a configuration file like that.

Is there a Subversion repository browser that takes username/password information from the user and uses that to authenticate any SVN requests made on their behalf?

EDIT:  I should state that we already *have* a SVN repository served through authenticated HTTPS.  We access this through thick clients like TortoiseSVN and Subclipse.  I'm looking for a web-based client that provides browsing through previous revisions, diffs, and so on, but which doesn't require pre-configured authentication information to connect to the repository.

Answer (score 4):

SVN can actually be served up through Apache and allow LDAP authentication. I've set this up before.

There is a prepackaged windows snap-in like server that is kept current with SVN versions called VisualSVN, this is basically an SVN repository served through and apache wrapper with the LDAP modules built.

http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2007/03/subversion_ldap.html

http://www.visualsvn.com/

This would keep you from having to maintain credentials within SVN. At least passwords.

I must note, VisualSVN **Server** is freeware and requires no licensing

Comment: I must note, VisualSVN **Server** is freeware and requires no licensing.

Comment: We don't maintain authentication credentials within SVN, we're already serving the repository via Apache with domain-based authentication.

I'm looking for a *client* that doesn't require additional authentication.

Comment: You're wanting a browser based client or any client? TortoiseSVN will allow you to save your credentials, depending on your password policy this could be a problem to change every 30 days or so. Other than that, not sure of any client that really supports domain authentication passed to the server.

Comment: I've looked for the same thing for a while, we actually ended up using the SharpSVN API wrapper for .NET and writing our own SVN client/project management software and keeping user logs based on AD ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

ViewVC 1.1.x, supports the Subversion authz rules.  The latest version of ViewVC is included with CollabNet Subversion Edge.  If you install Subversion Edge, there is a web UI to edit the Subversion authz rules and both the Subversion server and ViewVC are configured to use these same rules.  So there is nothing for you to do on the configuration side and you even get the ability to edit the file from your web browser.

If you want to configure ViewVC yourself, you just need to install it and configure the viewvc.conf file so that it is pointed at your authz rules.  The comments in the file point you in the right direction.

Get ViewVC here:

http://www.viewvc.org/

Get Subversion Edge (which includes Apache, Subversion and ViewVC) here:

http://www.open.collab.net/products/subversion/getit.html

Mark

Comment: This sounds like it would duplicate the authentication and authorization that out SVN HTTP server is already doing.

Standalone SVN clients exist that use individual user credentials; there must be a web client that can do this as well.

Comment: @Mark - this post seems out of date - could you revise?, e.g.: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/

Comment: I don't think you understood what I was asking.  From the current ViewVW FAQ section about remote SVN access, "If the auth credentials and such you need to access the remote repository aren't cached in ~VIEWVC_USER/.subversion (where VIEWVC_USER is the system user as whom ViewVC runs), stuff won't work."  It still requires /fixed credentials/ to access the SVN repository, it doesn't actually prompt the user for their SVN credentials.

Comment: In the case of Subversion Edge, the Subversion server and ViewVC run together on the same server.  So ViewVC does not access the server via remote access and does not require credentials.  That mode of using ViewVC has always only been experimental and does not perform well.  When ViewVC runs on the same server, it can prompt the user for credentials and use their credentials to determine access rights.